# methods logLikelihood and logPerplexity not available for Spark LDA, how to measure them?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, cluster-analysis, lda

I'm trying to get perplexity and log likelihood of a Spark LDA model (with Spark 2.1). The code below does not work (methods `logLikelihood` and `logPerplexity` not found) although I can save the model.

```python
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import LDA
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

# construct corpus
# run LDA
ldaModel = LDA.train(corpus, k=10, maxIterations=10)
logll = ldaModel.logLikelihood(corpus)
perplexity = ldaModel.logPerplexity(corpus)
```

Notice that such methods do not come up with `dir(LDA)`.

What would be a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can do train but not fit. 'LDA' object has no attribute 'fit'

That's because you are working with the old, [RDD-based API (MLlib)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda), i.e.

```python
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import LDA # WRONG import
```

whose `LDA` class indeed does **not** include `fit`, `logLikelihood`, or `logPerplexity` methods.

In order to work with these methods, you should switch to the new, [dataframe-based API (ML)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda):

```python
from pyspark.ml.clustering import LDA  # NOTE: different import

# Loads data.
dataset = (spark.read.format("libsvm")
    .load("data/mllib/sample_lda_libsvm_data.txt"))

# Trains a LDA model.
lda = LDA(k=10, maxIter=10)
model = lda.fit(dataset)

ll = model.logLikelihood(dataset)
lp = model.logPerplexity(dataset)
```